# eclipse with adt-bundle wont start - registry entry not found

Tags: eclipse-adt

Problem is with eclipse as modified for Android ADT. I installed adt-bundle-windows-x86_64.zip (downloaded 24feb2013), and kept it up to date ADT bundles and eclipse updates.

I updated the ADT (?) to version 22 recently. Android compilations failed (plain projects still worked), Mr Google told me to install something from near the top of the ADT Manager (?), which I did.

Now, when I invoke eclipse I get a dialog box with the following content:

```
An error has occurred. See the log file ...
```

The top of the log file is

```
!SESSION 2013-05-27 10:15:58.540 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685
java.version=1.7.0_15
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_AU
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-05-27 10:15:59.799
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-05-27 10:15:59.799
```

and the bottom is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.application, org.eclipse.cdt.core.GeneratePDOM, org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaIndexer, org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate, org.eclipse.update.core.siteOptimizer.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Eclipse doesn't use the registry (I believe) so this must be ADT. I'm concerned an uninstall+reinstall of eclipse won't clean the registry properly.

Can anyone advise on how to clean Android's ADT stuff out of the registry?

BTW, I'm running Windows 7.

I have run "eclipse -clean". It gave me the same dialog box.

Note: I do not get an eclipse window up. I can't access the settings menu, adt-manager, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel-> Advanced System Setting -> Environment Variables ->

Now:

1-Create a new variable variable name=JAVA_HOME

```
variable value=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01
```

2-Edit the Path variable and add this at the end of that

```
;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. Still get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I just uninstalled eclipse, and reinstalled. It's worked fine for a few weeks now.

Things that didn't work...

I downloaded and ran a registry-cleaner (not an editor). It made no difference.

I tried to install eclipse by itself and add the ADT bundle, but couldn't follow the instructions. They assumed I knew where some bundle had downloaded, but I didn't know. And because I had old bundles lying around, a file-search didn't help.

So, I gave in and downloaded Android's ADT + eclipse bundle. That's working.